# Table not shown as entity in ADO.NET. Is shown as an Association instead

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am writing my first `ASP.NET MVC` web application with simple `CRUD` operations into an `SQL` database. I added the database into `Visual Studio` using `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`. Everything was going smoothly until I realized that one of my tables is not shown as an entity in the EDMX diagram and is in the Associations folder instead.

Here is a screenshot of the SQL diagram, EDMX diagram and Model Browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49lW8.jpg

There are 5 tables:

```
Player - (PK)PlayerID
Season - (PK)SeasonID
Team- (PK)TeamID
SeasonTeam - (PK)SeasonID from Season
           - (PK)TeamID from Team
Roster - (PK)PlayerID from Player
       - (PK)SeasonID from SeasonTeam
       - (PK)TeamID from SeasonTeam
```

The `Player`, `Season`, `Team` and `SeasonTeam` table are shown as entities in the `EDMX` diagram, however the `Roster` table is not, and is shown as an association. How do I make the 'Roster' table an entity in ADO.NET?

Comment: Try to regenerate the EDMX file. Make sure you select All tables this time.

Comment: Tried deleting the EDMX and created it again, manually checking all the tables. Roster table still shown as association.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is because there is no entity relationship between Roster.TeamID and Team.TeamID from your ERD.

Comment: @randyh22 I want to use the primary key pair from `SeasonTeam` for the `Roster` table. Is it better to just use one primary key (ie. SeasonTeamID) in `SeasonTeam`?

Comment: Yes, If I were you, I would make an Id field in SeasonTeam an auto-incrementing int as PK and then use a SeasonTeamId foreign key field in Roster. Then also setup an Id field in Roster and make it PK there. Then just have the other Id fields in Roster be foreign keys to the other tables. This will make your life much easier in the long run and your CRUD operations much simpler.

Comment: If you take my advice above, you only need SeasonTeamId and PlayerId as fields in your Roster table.

Comment: @randyh22 Thanks! Roster is now its own entity after adding `SeasonTeamID` and `RosterID` in their respective tables. However, I still don't understand why `Player` and `SeasonTeam` is shown as a many-to-many relationship in VS if I don't add `RosterID` in the `Roster` table. `SeasonTeam` was shown as a 1-to-many relationship with `Season` and `Team` even without a unique ID.

Comment: It is many-to-many because a player can be on many rosters and a roster can have many players.

Comment: @randyh22 Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be not generated by default because your table has only Primary key

Comment: VS generated the SeasonTeam table which contains only foreign keys aswell. Does that mean VS doesn't generate table if a table contains a foreign key of a foreign key?

Comment: sorry, only Primary Key. Does your table Roster has all 3 fields as primary key? Also, does your SessionTeam has pair (SessionID + TeamID) as primary key too or simply 2 different foreign keys?

Comment: Yes, SeasonTeam has a primary key pair. Need to edit the OP as I mislabelled it. Would adding a unique ID for `Seasonteam` and recreating `Roster` as an associative entity with the `Player` table fix this?